# How to extract image metadata using MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, metadata, exif

How can I extract image metadata like exposure, width, height, or bitdepth using MATLAB?

Until recently I was using `exifread`, but this function no longer exists in the newest MATLAB version.

The other function is `imfinfo`, but it cannot read the 'EXPOSURE DATA' image.

How can I read the 'exposure' image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exifread()` deprecated 9 years ago. It has been replaced by `imfinfo`

`info = imfinfo(filename)` will return all information you want.

From the [Matlab reference](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imfinfo.html)

> **Additional fields returned by some file formats:**
>
> JPEG and TIFF only — If filename contains Exchangeable Image File
>   Format (EXIF) tags, then info might also contain 'DigitalCamera' or
>   'GPSInfo' (global positioning system information) fields.

`info.Width`, `info.Height`, `info.BitDepth`.
The exposuretime as well as all other camera parameters are stored in the 1x1 struct `info.DigitalCamera`

Here's an example from

https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/146651-missing-functionality-when-using-imfinfo-instead-of-exifread

```
>> info = imfinfo('img_1771.jpg')
info = 
            Filename: 'C:\Users\fhempel\Desktop\tmp\img_1771.jpg'
         FileModDate: '07-Aug-2014 12:09:45'
            FileSize: 32764
              Format: 'jpg'
       FormatVersion: ''
               Width: 480
              Height: 360
            BitDepth: 24
           ColorType: 'truecolor'
     FormatSignature: ''
     NumberOfSamples: 3
        CodingMethod: 'Huffman'
       CodingProcess: 'Sequential'
             Comment: {}
                Make: 'Canon'
               Model: 'Canon PowerShot S40'
         Orientation: 1
         XResolution: 180
         YResolution: 180
      ResolutionUnit: 'Inch'
            DateTime: '2003:12:14 12:01:44'
    YCbCrPositioning: 'Centered'
       DigitalCamera: [1x1 struct]
       ExifThumbnail: [1x1 struct]


>> info.DigitalCamera
ans = 
                ExposureTime: 0.0020
                     FNumber: 4.9000
                 ExifVersion: [48 50 50 48]
            DateTimeOriginal: '2003:12:14 12:01:44'
           DateTimeDigitized: '2003:12:14 12:01:44'
     ComponentsConfiguration: 'YCbCr'
      CompressedBitsPerPixel: 5
           ShutterSpeedValue: 8.9688
               ApertureValue: 4.6563
           ExposureBiasValue: 0
            MaxApertureValue: 2.9709
                MeteringMode: 'CenterWeightedAverage'
                       Flash: 'Flash did not fire, no strobe return detection function, auto flash mode, f...'
                 FocalLength: 21.3125
                   MakerNote: [1x450 double]
                 UserComment: [1x264 double]
             FlashpixVersion: [48 49 48 48]
                  ColorSpace: 'sRGB'
            CPixelXDimension: 2272
            CPixelYDimension: 1704
         InteroperabilityIFD: [1x1 struct]
       FocalPlaneXResolution: 8.1143e+03
       FocalPlaneYResolution: 8.1143e+03
    FocalPlaneResolutionUnit: 2
               SensingMethod: 'One-chip color area sensor'
                  FileSource: 'DSC'
              CustomRendered: 'Normal process'
                ExposureMode: 'Auto exposure'
                WhiteBalance: 'Auto white balance'
            DigitalZoomRatio: 1
            SceneCaptureType: 'Standard'
```

Answer (score 0):

All the information you think you are missing is stored in `iminfo`, just differently. Most of the parameters you want (including exposure data) are in

```
info=iminfo(fname);
info.DigitalCamera
```