How to extract image information from it (focal length, sensor size in mm )
I am writing a program (in MATLAB) where I need to have the focal length and sensor size for each photo in order to do the next calculations (now manually and by searching for the name of the camera or through the Image>Properties>Details section and these variables are different for each image)
Image>Properties>Details
But I need my program to call this information directly. I read in other places that this can be done using the imageinfo and imfinfo function, but I don't see the focal length in the information.
% Read the input images
image1 = imread('G:\سه بعدی سازی\پوشش های مختلف\9\drone_dataset_sand_key-master\DJI_0379.JPG');
info = imfinfo('G:\سه بعدی سازی\پوشش های مختلف\9\drone_dataset_sand_key-master\DJI_0379.JPG')

output whith imfinfo function:

output whith imfinfo function:

output whith imageinfo function:

Of course, I saw on this page( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55470926/how-to-extract-image-metadata-using-matlab ) that the focal length information was taken, but I could not.
What is the problem, how can I write a program that directly obtains the focal length?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
